# Create table with less borders

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to create using only HTML and CSS(no bootstrap) table that has border only between rows:

[image: )_]

Comment: Sure, it is simple.

Comment: Bootstrap is "only" a CSS Framework, you can do everything without it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set border bottom for `tr` as

```
tr{
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
tr{
border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}

td, th {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4):

```css
table { 
    border-collapse: collapse; 
}

tr + tr > td{
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Apple</td>
      <td>elppA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bad</td>
      <td>daB</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cat</td>
      <td>taC</td>
    </tr>
    
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

in addition to the other answers, I put the color and the 'distance' with width

```css
table { 
    border-collapse: collapse; 
    width:100%;
}

tr + tr > td{
  border-top: 1px solid #dee2e6;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Mary</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>July</td>
      <td>Whats</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Thomas</td>
    
      <td>Simon</td>
    </tr>
    
  </tbody>
</table>
```

For answer your comment Micheal:

- The “+” sign selector is used to select the elements that are placed immediately after the specified element but not inside the particular elements. [Reference](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-does-the-plus-sign-css-selector-mean/#:%7E:text=The%20%E2%80%9C%2B%E2%80%9D%20sign%20selector%20is,not%20inside%20the%20particular%20elements.)
- The greater than sign (>) selector in CSS is used to select the element with a specific parent. [Reference](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-greater-than-sign-selector-in-css/#:%7E:text=The%20greater%20than%20sign%20(%3E),direct%20children%20of%20a%20parent.)